# How to find year and Month from no of days passed in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have the amount of days passed , I want to find out the month and year for that particular day gap using big query SQL

> For eg:    I have the following fields :  date_today as DATE ,  day_passed
>   as INTEGER

```
    date_today = '2018-01-22'    
    day_passed =  32
```

From this day passed I want to create a new column like below using day_passed column value

```
    month_joined = '2017-12'
```

Challenge: Months may have different days In Feb(28 or 29),30,31

What will be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use [DATE_ADD()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In tsql you can use this query which I suggest you modify into a function.

```
declare @date nvarchar(20) = '2018-01-22'
declare @interval int = -32
declare @newDate datetime =  DATEADD(DAY,@interval,CAST(@date as datetime))
select cast(year(@newDate) as nvarchar(4)) +'-'+ cast(month(@newDate) as nvarchar(2)) as 'month_joined'
```

To create into a function in tsql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION YearMonthConvert(
    @Date datetime,
    @Interval int = 0)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newDate datetime = DATEADD(DAY,@Interval,CAST(@Date as datetime))
    RETURN cast(year(@newDate) as nvarchar(4)) +'-'+ cast(month(@newDate) as nvarchar(2))
END;
```

then it can be called like this:

```
select dbo.yearmonthconvert('2018-01-22',-32)
```

I believe the mysql syntax is as follows - not done mysql so if anyone wants to correct me in the comments that would be much appreciated.

```
set @date  = '2018-01-22';
set @interval = -32;
set month_joined = DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL @interval DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql functons
[DATE_SUB](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp)
or 
[DATE_ADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

SELECT DATE_SUB('2018-01-22', INTERVAL 32 DAY)
Result:
2017-12-21

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL
It should give you an idea of how you can work with dates in BigQuery

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  date_today, 
  day_passed,
  DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY) day_joined,
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY), MONTH) month_joined_as_date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY)) month_joined_as_string
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

you can test / play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-22' date_today, 32 day_passed
)
SELECT 
  date_today, 
  day_passed,
  DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY) day_joined,
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY), MONTH) month_joined_as_date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE_SUB(date_today, INTERVAL day_passed DAY)) month_joined_as_string
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

with result

```sql
date_today  day_passed  day_joined  month_joined_as_date    month_joined_as_string
2018-01-22  32          2017-12-21  2017-12-01              2017-12
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it in a simple way in bigquery

```
SUBSTR(STRING(DATE_ADD(DATE(date_today), -day_passed, "DAY")),1,7) AS month_joined
```